# Error en el LIMIT

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema , y quiero usar un `LIMIT`, pero me sale un error en `SQL Server`.

la consulta es:

```
SELECT * FROM historia
ORDER BY data_ultcol DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

El error dice:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>
> Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'LIMIT'.

Muchas Gracias por la colaboración

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas con capturas de pantalla en lugar de código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Edité tu respuesta, pero, pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba el siguiente código:

```
SELECT  *
FROM     historia
ORDER BY data_ultcol 
OFFSET  1 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, este select me sirvió mucho

Comment: Por favor, si te sirvió, califica la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

`Sql Server` no permite usar la instrucción `Limit`. Para hacer lo que quieres debes usar la instrucción `Top`, mas info [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp).

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM historia
ORDER BY data_ultcol DESC
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por aclararme lo de la instrucción LIMIT, Quiero sacar es el penúltimo registro ordenándolo por fecha de forma desc, de pronto sabe si con el TOP, se puede hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es seleccionar la primera fila, deberías ponerlo así:

```
Select TOP 1 * from historia order by data_ultcol
```

La expresión LIMIT no existe en SQL.